# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have seen many similar questions on SO and as far as I can see all of them suggest that we should not push/pop any views while either the current view 'viewWillAppear' has not being called or the 'isViewLoaded' call returns false.

In my instance, I try to push a new view in the current view 'viewWillAppear' method and before I push it I also call [self isViewLoaded] to see if the current view is loaded (which is) yet I still keep getting the above error.

The only way I was able to solve this (which is a hack) is to sleep for few seconds before I call the push on a different non UI thread.

Since sleeping for few seconds before the call actually makes the pushing works, I assume that although both 'viewWillAppear' is already called and [self isViewLoaded] is true, it is still be sometimes too early to push/pop another view (maybe do to animation still not complete?).

I'm I missing something? Is there any other method other than 'viewWillAppear' or   [self isViewLoaded] that will indicate %100 that the view has completely loaded and all animations are complete so I can safely push/pop other views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try it in viewDidAppear.

however, what scenario/design you had in mind when implementing this?
IMO, it is a bad design to immediately push a new view controller from the view that isn't loaded yet.

Comment: Thanks will try that later today and let you know if that works (need to leave now). I agree that this is not the best design, but basically when the I instantiate the first view I also make a webservice call and get back some data. Depending on the data I will either stay on the same view or navigate to a different view. Refactoring this flow at the moment is not an option unless everything else fails.